# Numeric value error in Aboss (theme of OpenCart)

Tags: php, opencart, numeric

I got a theme for OpenCart 3.0.2.0 called Aboss, and it has an error. My php knowledge is still extremely weak, almost nonexistent, and the theme developer support can take up to 3 business days to respond, so I would like help to solving the problem.

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojabootkamp\catalog\model\hozmegamenu\menu.php on
>   line 488 Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lojabootkamp\catalog\model\hozmegamenu\menu.php on
>   line 489

```
function partition_element(Array $list, $p) {
    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++) {
        $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
}
```

Line 488 contains:

```
$partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
```

Line 489 contains:

```
$partrem = $listlen % $p;
```

Any attempt to help is welcome, I really need it. Please try to be as specific as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Heya. What is `$p`?

Comment: I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems like `$p` is passed as a string.
What i did was **(LINE 479)**:

```
if ($count) {
    $parentCates = $this->partition_element($parentCates,(int)$num);
}
```

As you can see. I put a (int) before number.

Hope it helps

This is working perfectly